# Automatic Saving doesn't work in TeXShop 5.22, MacTeX 2023 and Ventura 13.6.1

Tags: mac, texshop

How to start **Automatic Saving** in TeXShop?
It doesn't work in TeXShop 5.22, MacTeX 2023, Ventura 13.6.1

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with doesn't work? Please explain your issue better!

Comment: The changes are not automatically saved. I have to save the changes bij CMD+s.